# $f:X \rightarrow X$ continuous function such that $f(x)=f(f(x))$. Prove $f$ is a quotient map.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $f:X \rightarrow X$ a continuous function such that $f(x)=f(f(x))$ for all $x \in X$. Prove $f$ is a quotient map.

It's easy if we have $f$ is surjective because by hypothesis we have $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(f^{-1}(U))$ then $U=f(f^{-1}(f^{-1}(U)))=f^{-1}(U)$ for all open set in $X$ but $f$ is not necessarily surjective function, what can I do?

Comment: What is your definition of "quotient map"?  There is a little bit of variety here.

Comment: Also, where did the problem come from?

Comment: In this case, $f$ is quotient map if $$U \subset X \text{ is open} \iff f^{-1}(U) \subset X  \text{ is open }$$

Comment: And my teacher gave me a list of exercises, where one of them is this problem.

Comment: Something is wrong here.  Any constant function satisfies the hypotheses of the exercise but then the preimage of _any set_ is open, as the only possible preimages are $\emptyset, X$.

Comment: If $f$ is surjective, then $f$ is the identity function. Yes, a quotient function, but only trivially so. Technically, you probably want to say the function that sends $X$ to the range of $f$ and otherwise equal to $f$ is a quotient function. This can be written in terms of the surjective-injectiive factorization, $f=i\circ p$ where $p$ is surjective and $i$ is injective. Then $p$ is a quotient map.

Comment: Then $f\circ f=f$ becomes $i\circ p\circ i\circ p=i\circ p,$ and since $i$ is injective, you get $p\circ i\circ p=p.$

Comment: I feel 99% certain this is just asking to show the map is a quotient when viewed as a surjection onto its image.  That makes it an elementary exercise but not trivial for someone new to the various definitions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews guess I should have read your comment before I answered, thank you for providing a rigorous interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

This statement is false, for example, take $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be $f(x)=0$.
Then ${0}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not open but $f^{-1}({0})=\mathbb{R}$ which is open.

Usually part of the definition of a quotient map is being surjective, so I think this should be another requirement for $f$.

Comment: If $f$ is surjective and $f(f(x))=f(x),$ then $f$ is the identity. So it is a quotient map, but trivially. Don't think that is the clarification the question needs.

Comment: Oh, you are totally right.

Comment: I misread that line in the question as "It's easy to see that" rather than "It's easy to see if." @BrianMoehring

Answer (score 1):

Since quotient maps are surjective, it is logical to interpret the question as asking to prove that $f$ is a quotient map when viewed as a map $f\colon X\to A$, where $A=f(X)$ is equipped with the subspace topology.

To see this, recall that by definition, we must show $f^{-1}(U)$ is open if and only if $U$ is open, for any $U\subseteq A$.

One direction of this is immediate from continuity - if $U\subseteq A$ is open in $A$, then certainly $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Conversely, if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, then $f^{-1}(U)\cap A$ is open in the subspace topology.  But we always have $U=f^{-1}(U)\cap A$ (since $f$ restricts to the identity on $f(X)=A$), hence $U$ is open in $A$.

[Edit:  Technically, to make the above rigorous, we should follow Thomas Andrews' suggestion from the comments and write $f=i\circ p$, where $i\colon f(X)\to X$ is an inclusion and $p\colon X\to f(X)$ agrees with $f$ at every point, and then argue that $p$ is a quotient map, by replacing $f$ with $p$ in the above argument.]

##### Remark

A map $f$ as described here is called a *retraction*, and $A$ is called a *retract* of $X$.